# Eclipse Java EE no encuentra javax.servlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat

estoy montando un nuevo server, como siempre en un **Eclipse Mars (4.5.2) Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers**, tuve un problema con la instalación del servidor, lo borré y encontré [este bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791843/eclipse-add-tomcat-7-blank-server-name) que ya esté solucionado, pero ahora, al importar la base del proyecto me dice...

```
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que puedo importar la libreria manualmente... pero teniendo en cuenta que tengo el eclipse adecuado no tiene por qué hacerse, ademas eso me daría futuros problemas....

Comment: El eclipse no tiene nada que ver en que falten librerías, eso viene con el SDK.

Comment: @Deoxyseia no pueden faltar estas librerias, es eclipse EE... pero encontré la respuesta (más abajo) `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucionado... `:S`. Lo pongo aqui por si a alguien le pasa en un futuro (a mi no me habia pasado esto nunca).

**NOTA: debes tener instalado Eclipse Java EE, sino no intentes esta solución!!!**

---

La previa instalacion fallida del tomcat que me llevo al [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791843/eclipse-add-tomcat-7-blank-server-name) se había quedado clavada en las configuraciones de eclipse (**eso me pasa por borrar a mano el tomcat**).

En las **Propiedades del Proyecto > Targeted runtimes** estaba mi antigua instalación de tomcat (la que ya no existía) seleccionada y la nueva desmarcada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA:** *cuando he vuelto a entrar para hacer la captura solo muestra el tomcat válido, pero la primera vez que he entrado había 2 instancias de tomcat y estaba marcada la incorrecta! Aunque si desmarcas la buena, puedes reproducir el error.* `:)`

Comment: Yo desarrollo aplicaciones Java EE con Eclipse para Java SE. El truco: no utilizar ant (que es para este tipo de proyectos) sino maven o gradle donde puedes agregar estas librerías en modo provisto y el IDE las reconoce.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza en este caso el build o los repos, ya sean con maven/ant creo que no tienen nada que ver... es un problema de configuracion de eclipse causado por un error previo

Comment: Sí tienen que ver. Como te digo, yo no utilizo Eclipse para Java EE, utilizo el Eclipse para Java plano que es más ligero, tiene menos plugins y menos configuraciones que realizar, levanta más rápido y me permite ser flexible con el grupo de tecnologías que utilizo, ya sea aplicaciones Web o de cualquier otro tipo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no, no tienen que ver si instalas Java EE. El que tu uses un metodo diferente para trabajar no importa aqui, es más, creo que molesta y confunde a futuros usuarios. **Primero**, existe una version de Eclipse EE, por algo sera, no? **segundo** si lees atentamente, y aunque admito que borrar el tomcat a mano no es la mejor idea, hay un bug declarado, cosa que claramente indica que ni soy el primero ni el último (confirmalo mirando la respuesta borrada agradeciendo el post)

Comment: y **tercero**, he posteado la pregunta y respuesta para futuros usuarios que tengan el problema Y TRABAJEN CON ECLIPSE EE como pone claramente al principio de la respuesta, asi que creo recomendar borrar el IDE y trabajar con otra version no es una solución en este caso, pero si crees que lo es, postealo como respuesta y no en los comentarios, porque aqui es un dato innecesario por tu parte y no aporta nada.

Comment: Es que tu respuesta se limita a uso de tomcat. En realidad puedes usar cualquier otro servidor de aplicaciones o contenedor de servlets, eso es indistinto, pero aquí es como si tu proyecto se amarrara a ello, lo cual para una aplicación multi plataforma como es Java contradice un poco esto. Es más, puedes resolver el problema descargando las librerías de serlvets directamente y agregarlas en el classpath del proyecto y te olvidas de tomcat. A mí me parece (como usuario) que este tipo de respuestas son las que limitan el conocimiento de cómo resolver un problema.

Comment: @Luiggi el problema es que eclipse EE no reconoce la clase servlet despues de borrar tomcat. Que pasa? que ni compila!! nadie obliga a usar java o eclipse, pero alguien tiene un problema con ellos no le puedes decir que se pasen a `c++` o `intelliJ`. No te gusta tomcat? me parece bien pero es quien causa un bug en una version de eclipse EE que no se arregla descargando librerias, **es un error garrafal y estas confundiendo a futuros usuarios porque intentaran instalar librerias que ya tienen por culpa de un bug del servidor**. Lee bien las cosas antes de dar opiniones,que eres mod tio

Comment: o no entiendes que despues de este error no podras montar ningun servidor porque eclipse no ve las librerias por culpa de una configuracion engtanchada???

Comment: Si agregas las librerías, el servidor de aplicaciones que uses es indistinto...